# CSS div with background color and opacity and text inside div

Tags: html, css, opacity

I have this div:

```
<div class="entry-content" style="background: rgba(160, 160, 160); opacity:0.5; display:inline-block; border-radius: 5px; padding:20px;">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis quis mauris leo. Pellentesque vehicula nunc nec volutpat lobortis. Aliquam pretium felis non ullamcorper bibendum. Donec mollis velit porta ipsum euismod, id aliquet felis auctor. Fusce lacinia fermentum mi eu elementum. Sed dignissim elit a ullamcorper ornare. Proin a justo id risus suscipit condimentum vitae ac purus. Nunc nec lacinia justo, vitae elementum leo. Phasellus sit amet suscipit orci. Cras id mi eget nunc scelerisque condimentum commodo a est. Aliquam a tortor a metus hendrerit commodo eu quis felis. In dictum semper ante sit amet faucibus.</p>
</div>
```

and the opacity is working a little too well, as my text has the opacity applied to it also...whats the best way to fix this issue?

Comment: why not set `rgba(160, 160, 160, .5)` instead of setting `opacity:.5` for your div? There is no way to keep the div's children's opacity at `1` while the opacity of the div itself is `.5`

Comment: @KingKing He's also doubling up on the opacity as well, which makes no sense. Your best option, if you wish to keep the opacity on `entry-content` is to add another div inside it that has a `position:absolute` and fill the parent div. After, which, you can apply the opacity on it. You may also need to apply a `z-index` to the inner div so it shows underneath the text.

Answer (score 0):

You have used

```
   rgba(160, 160, 160,0.5);
```

using the 4th parameter you can set the opacity of the background. 
And using

```
   opacity:0.5
```

You set the opacity of the div's content. Fix it by just using rgba and no need for opacity.